# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 and PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Seems like Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 has PHP syntax highlighting. But is there any way to create PHP files or projects from VS itself? If yes, how can I create one?

P.S. Don't suggest vs.php (jcx.software) please, as I'm looking for it's alternative.

Comment: Hey I'm one of the developers for VS.Php what are you disliking about it?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just create and empty project and add files? While I love the support MS is giving PHP lately, I would not expect them to go as far as creating php project templates that would full on compete with ASP.Net